# Overriding IP packet TTLs

Tags: networking, ip

I've hit a situation at work where we are communicating with an external network and we are observing partial packet loss due to ttls being decremented to zero. However, Some traffic does arrive and the issue manifests as failures only on some connections. The root cause is currently unknown. The OS in question is linux on our side and unknown, but likely linux on the external network. One of my colleagues is proposing that we rewrite the ttl on all packets entering and exiting a proxy box which is is used on this route. This seems like a bad idea to me, but I can't pin down why. Does anyone have insight on rewriting ttls?

Comment: Usually TTL reaching 0 means there is a loop in the communication (eg: outside -> box -> inside-router -> box -> inside-router -> box ... ). If that were the case, rewriting the TTL would just give the same result, with more duplicated packets created before reaching ttl 0. Beside the question is probably OS specific and there's no OS stated.

Comment: And if the rewrite happens *inside* the loop, then this could create a packet storm

Comment: If there is a loop it seems to be a probabilistic loop as some traffic does get through. Re-reading my post that point is ambiguous and I'll update it.

Comment: still missing the OS

Comment: Apologies. Updated again. Linux everywhere on our side.

Comment: A `traceroute` between your host and the remote host might be interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

The TTL is here to prevent loops to be infinite and allow looping traffic to be dropped at some time: when the TTL reaches 0. Rewriting the TTL might prevent this mechanism to trigger and bring involved nodes to their demise if enough traffic is injected to add more loops upon loops.

Normally the sane way would be to capture traffic at various points in network to see what happens with packets and their TTL, and especially to check if the same packet is seen multiple times on the same point except with a decrementing TTL value, strongly hinting at a loop. This might look difficult on network with heavy traffic, but the capture can be limited for example to packets having a TTL <= 5.

---

### iptables

Anyway Here's enough rope to hang oneself. Linux has various tools working at various network layers to rewrite a TTL value. Among them are [`tc`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-pedit.8), [`iptables`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#TTL_(IPv4-specific)) and [`nftables`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#PAYLOAD_STATEMENT). I'll use `iptables` because it provides an "increment" operation, so doesn't require to guess what would be a good value. Here's a rope-to-hang-oneself relevant quote from the man:

> Setting or incrementing the TTL field can potentially be very
> dangerous, so it should be avoided at any cost.

Incrementing by 1 will cancel the automatic decrement by 1 done when routing a packet (you can choose other options in the linked manpage, like incrementing more or using `--ttl-set 100`):

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
```

without additional matches in the rule, it will apply whenever a packet is routed, in any direction.

Comment: Oh we already have plenty of rope. Many thanks for the feedback.